# NSSet isEqualToSet returning false when comparing two NSSets having same NSString

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective C, and based on documentation i cannot figure out 
Why would it print "no" when same NSString values are there in two NSSets ?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {


        NSSet *set1 = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"seta1", @"setb1", nil];


        NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"seta1" @"setb1", nil];


        if([set1 isEqualToSet:set2]) {
            NSLog(@"yes");
        }else {
            NSLog(@"no");
        }



    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set1` contains two objects, `set2` only one:

There is a comma missing in `set2` after `@"seta1"`